# Couldnt download IOS Application From diawi?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, macos

I created an app and define `UDID` on the developer account. Then I created IPA file for distribution on Xcode. I uploaded it to diawi and I can see my UDIDs on diawi. Everything is perfect. But when I click download, an error occurs:

```
application can not be downloaded, at the moment
```

How can I solve this? Any suggestions?

Comment: Try again later?

Comment: Tried again several times, also resetted the  device but nothing changed.

Comment: your provisional profile not contain that device id that's why it show error. Pls Edit your Provisional Profile and Select all devices before download and remove the previous install profile from system before install new profile and clear your cache and cookies in Safari. problem will resolve

Comment: you can use AppFinder app , it also very useful to share ipa

Answer (score 0):

You should make your `.ipa` with `adhoc distribution option`, if you have make `ipa` with `app store distrubution` then it will not work on `diawi` I think! So, make sure that you are selecting adhoc distribution when creating your `ipa`!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and I resolved in following way.

1. Connect the device with MAC.
2. Open Organizer then chooses devices.
   3  Choose your Connected device from the sidebar.
3. Choose Console inside the chosen device.
4. Now install the app it will show the exact cause of the problem.

In my case, I was trying to install the app on a lower version of iOS. When you will get the exact cause you can resolve it. It may be different than mine in your case.